# presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated fullscreen notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

To display a video I use this:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

and enter automatically in Full-Screen, but I can't handle the notification with this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
```

The method `moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` isn't called. How can I detect when the video starts playing in fullscreen?

Comment: set your notification before [self.movieController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

Comment: i haven't self.movieController where you read it?

Comment: its just a suggestion, in your case [videoPlayerViewController  setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

Comment: Just to make sure it's not a silly typo, in your code line it's shown as `moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:` but then you refer to it as `moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` (without the `:`). Can you confirm that the method takes a parameter?

Comment: yes takes a parameter :)